# log in when I click a button

Tags: android

I think this problem easy but there is something I can not figure out 
here is a xml file has some widjet and there is an comment button and I want to check when the user click the button if he has an account , if it's not I want to take him to sing in activity ,
I know that I should check for an id or something 
sorry for this silly question I will appreciate

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="life.insomnia.inception.movie_Detailes">



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/poster"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/split" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/poster"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:height="60dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#fff"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tag_line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/poster"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="mdfxvcmvcbnjxmk,x.,cmvbvncmx,;x,cmvncm,;zlx,cmvncmx,zlxkcmvnbvncmx,jzlfjfksdhmjkhfdsdhfkjjslknscnfgskjdpodjakdksjflkfuiweroihjszfdlkfhsoifhsdkgushfjdfkgh"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/commenttxt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="comment here"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tag_line"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/commentbtn"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/commenttxt"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand your question

Comment: Your xml is irrelevant at this point. You need to explain what isn't working and post an example of what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

You add an ID to the button:

```
android:id="@+id/someId"
```

And then in code:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.someId);
b.setOnClickListener(this);//Make sure the class implements onClickListener
```

then in `onClick(View v)`

```
switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.someId:
        //login here
    break;
}
```